# partial unique on strings within file - keep only the first string available

Tags: text-processing, macos

I have a file called `my_file.txt` that contains the following strings:

```
tasmax_day_ACCESS_historical_r1i1p1f3_gn.nc
tasmax_day_EC-Earth3_historical_r1i1p1f1_gn.nc
tasmax_day_EC-Earth3_historical_r1i1p1f1_gr.nc
tasmax_day_EC-Earth3_historical_r1i1p1f3_gn.nc
tasmax_day_HadGEM-MM_historical_r1i1p1f1_gn.nc
tasmax_day_HadGEM-MM_historical_r1i1p1f1_gr.nc
tasmax_day_HadGEM-MM_historical_r3i1p1f1_gn.nc
tasmax_day_MIROC_historical_r1i1p1f1_gn.nc
tasmax_day_MIROC_historical_r2i1p1f1_gn.nc
```

I need to perform a `unique` of the substring starting with `tasmax` end ending in `_historical` where for each such substring I would keep only that line containing it that comes first in alphabetical order.

My expected output of `my_file.txt` is the following:

```
tasmax_day_ACCESS_historical_r1i1p1f3_gn.nc
tasmax_day_EC-Earth3_historical_r1i1p1f1_gn.nc
tasmax_day_HadGEM-MM_historical_r1i1p1f1_gn.nc
tasmax_day_MIROC_historical_r1i1p1f1_gn.nc
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple Awk would suffice. Form a hash-map, keyed by the unique identifier string and print only those lines

```bsh
awk -F_ '{ key = $1 FS $2 FS $3 $4 } !unique[key]++ ' file
```

With the delimiter set to `_`, access the individual works by `$1` notation and form the key upto including `$4`. The expression `!unique[key]++` will be non-zero only if the key (formed) from the line is *not* already seen.

This *assumes* your `tasmax` string occurs at `$1` and `historical` at `$4` and does not work otherwise.

---

Or just use the `sort` tool, asking it to unique (`-u`) lines by delimiting on `_` using fields `1-4`. Works on both BSD and GNU `sort` variants

```bsh
sort -u -t_ -k1,4 < file
```

Comment: thanks it works

Comment: I was just thinking this was a job for awk. (or perl if you into that.)

Comment: `sort` seems to be faster

Comment: don't know about velocity but definitely sort solution much more intuitive :)